# With the free account of Firebase is it possible to backup firestore? How?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have Spark plan (free) and I would like to backup the Firestore Data. I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNT_9d0gAFQ) but it returns this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) PERMISSION_DENIED: This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/ then retry. If you enabled billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Is there a way to to backup it WITHOUT UPGRADING TO BLAZE? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit:

> This API method requires billing to be enabled.

The documentation on [exporting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) also has this note:

> Firebase projects must be on the Blaze plan to use the managed export and import feature. Enabling billing for the Google Cloud automatically upgrades your Firebase project to the Blaze plan.

So it looks like your project will need to be on the Blaze plan to use scheduled exports.

Comment: And there is a way to backup up without blaze?

Comment: Well... you can read the data through the API, as this also does: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore